# Python BS4 crawler indexerror

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple crawler that pulls meta data from websites and saves the information into a csv. So far I am stuck here, I have followed some guides but am now stuck with the error:

IndexError: list of index out of range.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Copy all of the content from the provided web page
webpage = urlopen('http://www.tidyawaytoday.co.uk/').read()

# Grab everything that lies between the title tags using a REGEX
patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')

# Grab the link to the original article using a REGEX
patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel.*href="(.*)" />')

# Store all of the titles and links found in 2 lists
findPatTitle = re.findall(patFinderTitle,webpage)
findPatLink = re.findall(patFinderLink,webpage)

# Create an iterator that will cycle through the first 16 articles and skip a few
listIterator = []
listIterator[:] = range(2,16)

# Print out the results to screen
for i in listIterator:
    print findPatTitle[i] # The title
    print findPatLink[i] # The link to the original article

articlePage = urlopen(findPatLink[i]).read() # Grab all of the content from original article

divBegin = articlePage.find('<div>') # Locate the div provided
article = articlePage[divBegin:(divBegin+1000)] # Copy the first 1000 characters after the div

# Pass the article to the Beautiful Soup Module
soup = BeautifulSoup(article)

# Tell Beautiful Soup to locate all of the p tags and store them in a list
paragList = soup.findAll('p')

# Print all of the paragraphs to screen
for i in paragList:
    print i
    print '\n'

# Here I retrieve and print to screen the titles and links with just Beautiful Soup
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(webpage)

print soup2.findAll('title')
print soup2.findAll('link')

titleSoup = soup2.findAll('title')
linkSoup = soup2.findAll('link')

for i in listIterator:
    print titleSoup[i]
    print linkSoup[i]
    print '\n'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error I get is

```
File "C:\Users......", line 24, in (module)
   print findPatTitle[i] # the title
IndexError:list of index out of range
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you narrow this down to *where exactly* you get the error? At an absolute minimum, the full traceback would be much more useful than just the final line. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So what's the value of `i`, and what (if anything) is in `findPatTitle`?

Comment: `print(len(findPatTitle))` and `print(len(findPatLink))` will enlighten you

Comment: `listIterator = range(2,16)` is sufficient and use BeautifulSoup to extract the  title etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not using all the power that bs4 can give you.

You are getting this error because the lenght of patFinderTitle is just one, since all html has usually only one title element per document.

A simple way to grab the title of a HTML, is using bs4 itself:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

webpage = urlopen('http://www.tidyawaytoday.co.uk/').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)

# get the content of title
title = soup.title.text
```

You will probably get the same error if you try to iterate over your findPatLink in the currently way, since it has length 6. For me, it is not clear enough if you want to get all the link elements or all the anchor elements, but stickying with the first idea, you can improve your code using bs4 again:

```
link_href_list = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all("link")]
```

And finally, since you don't want some urls, you can slice link_href_list in the way that you want. An improved version of the last expression which excludes the first and the second result could be:

```
link_href_list = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all("link")[2:]]
```